# Has anyone else's rep dropped and stopped updating?

Tags: support, reputation

I suddenly lost 50 points on SO, and since then have not gained rep despite a bunch of upvotes (still under the 200 rep cap).

Update: my daily rep earned was 247, then dropped to 197 and since then has not budged, despite upvotes.

Comment: +1 Here just gave you rep, is this only on SO?

Comment: Yes, only on SO.

Comment: The rep responds to downvotes, but not upvotes.

Comment: Have you downvoted anyone, or given out a bounty today? Those rep lost will not be compensated.

Comment: @Kenny: No, no bounty or downvotes.

Comment: @Kenny: Ok, so somehow I suddenly dropped 50 points? Would those not be logged in my profile? Hard for me to imagine losing that much.

Comment: @Red: Maybe you could check the rep report http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Kenny: the report looks helpful, but it is behind by 253 points, so I'll have to wait a bit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably you hit the rep cap with those 247 points, so that upvotes won't count anymore for the day.

Then one of the questions that you answered, and for which you gained 50 points, got deleted.

Now the "recent" rep tab only shows the still existing upvotes, but new ones still don't count since you already hit the cap today.

Comment: Thx, that sounds likely.

Comment: If the question was deleted, wouldn't I be able to re-earn those points? Or is it that once you hit the cap, that's it, regardless of subsequent events (excluding accepts of course).

Comment: oh, and, of course, +1 :)

Comment: There have been some changes how the cap works (accepted also contributed to the cap,...) and I don't know for sure how it works since. *Before the change* you stayed capped once you were, even if something got deleted (here it happened to me: [screenshot](http://tejp.de/files/linked/img/so-replimit.png)). Your description of the problem sounds like it still works that way.